# Ссылка которую я привязал к кнопке действует на всю ширину страницы

Tags: html, css, изображения, ссылки

Уже 3 час не могу понять в чем ошибка код ниже. В гугле вообще не смог найти ответа.У меня получается что ссылка которую я привязал к кнопке действует во всю ширину страницы.

```css
#but1{
    background-color:#fff;
    border:none;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin: 12px 50px -30px 1040px;
    font-size:12px;
    width:117px;
    height: 48px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#but1:hover{
    background-color:#f5f6f8;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <a href="#">
            <button id="but1">Switch to English</button>
        </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Margin я использовал что бы задать своей кнопке координаты

Comment: если надо задать координаты, то задаются именно координаты top,left, например с абсолютным позиционированием, а не отступы. Если надо кнопку выровнять по правому краю, то тоже делают соответствующими средствами.

Comment: Спасибо, я недавно начал изучать css.

Comment: По спецификации кнопка `<button>` не может быть внутри элемента `<a>`. Такой HTML изначально неправильный.